# How to set Cookie in Electron React using npm react-cookie package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, electron, react-cookie

i am trying to set cookie in electron-react app using npm [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie) package

and setting cookie like that

```
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies();
setCookie("isWorking", 121, { path: "/" });
```

its work fine in development mode but as i build electron application its not set my cookies
in build application

SnapShot of cookies in development

[image: SS_of_cookie]

Snapshot in Production/electron build application
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production, mode electron runs your react application in the file system so cookies never be saved in the file system in order to save cookies you have to run electron-react application in serve mode

```
  const server = require("./server");

    const createServer = async () => {
      if (isDev) {
        createWindow();
        win.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
      } else {
        let port = null;
        for (let i = 5001; i < 6000; i++) {
          let isFree = await isPortFree(i);
      
          if (isFree) {
            port = i;
            break;
          }
        }
        currentPort = port;
        server.listen(port, () => {
          console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
          createWindow();
          win.loadURL(`http://localhost:${currentPort}`);
        });
      }
    };
app.whenReady().then(createServer);
```

and you server.js file will be like that

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/app")));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/app/index.html"));
});

module.exports = app;
```